# Calculation of business hours between two date time fields

Tags: apex, businesshours

```
Id businessHoursId = [select Id from BusinessHours where isdefault = true ].id;
DateTime dateTime1 = Datetime.valueOf('2015-07-10 12:00:00');
DateTime dateTime2 = Datetime.valueOf('2015-07-13 12:00:00');
Long hours = Math.abs(BusinessHours.diff(businessHoursId,dateTime1,dateTime2)/1000/60/60);
Decimal days = hours / 24.0;
```

Above code gives 72 hours, but it should be 27 working hours. How can I modify this code to work as expected?

Comment: Are you sure you adjusted the days and hours for the associated default business hours so they do not say "24 hours" next to each day?

Comment: Eric, i dint understand how to adjust default business hours. I am new to sfdc dev. Is it possible for you to advice.

Answer (score 2):

You most likely (from your comment) have not set up the business hours so they are all set to the default of 24 Hours a day 7 days a week.

A quick google search for "Salesforce set up business hours" yielded this gem:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_supporthours.htm&type=0

> To set business hours:
>
> 1. From Setup, enter Business Hours in the Quick Find box, then select Business Hours.
> 2. Click New Business Hours.
> 3. Type a name for the business hours.
> 4. We recommend using a name that will remind users of a location or time zone when they view business hours on a case, entitlement
>      process, or milestone. For example, if your business hours are for a
>      support center in San Francisco, you could use the name San Francisco
>      Business Hours.
> 5. Click Active to allow users to associate the business hours with cases, escalation rules, milestones, and entitlement processes.
>      Optionally, click Use these business hours as the default to set the
>      business hours as the default business hours on all new cases. Default
>      business hours on cases can be updated with business hours on
>      escalation rules if the cases match escalation rule criteria and the
>      rule is set to override business hours.
> 6. Choose a time zone to associate with the business hours in the Time Zone drop-down list.
> 7. Set your business hours for each day of the week.
>
>    - If your support team is available during the entire day every day of the week, select the 24 hours checkbox.
>    - Choose the start and end times for the business hours. If the time you want isn’t available, click the field and type it in.
>    - Leave the business hours start and end times blank and the 24 hours checkbox deselected to indicate that the support team is not available
>        at all that day.
> 8. Click Save.

Comment: thanks Eric.    i updated business hours and using below code

Comment: public Long diff(Id businessHoursId, Datetime startDate, Datetime endDate)
    {
        
        DateTime dateTime1 = Datetime.valueOf('startDate');
        DateTime dateTime2 = Datetime.valueOf('endDate');
        Long hours = Math.abs(BusinessHours.diff(businessHoursId,dateTime1,dateTime2)/1000/60/60);
        Decimal days = hours / 24.0;
  system.debug('decimal days'+ hours );
     }

Comment: Id businessHoursId = [select Id from BusinessHours where isdefault = true ].id;
         ResponseTimeCal(businessHoursId,oppObj.createdDate,oppObj.Response_Date__c);       i am geting error, incorrect signature. but i dont c any error in the syntax